# How to set simulator location when using xcodebuild from the terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm running automated iOS UI tests and have been trying to figure out how to get the xcodebuild command through the terminal to accept a GPS location for the simulator.

If I set it with a GPX file in Scheme > Run > Options > Default Location, it works when I build the app in Xcode. And if I set it with a GPX file in the test plan Configurations > Simulated Location, it works when running tests through Xcode. But when running a test plan with xcodebuild through the terminal, it ignores everything and defaults to None.

The test plans will eventually be run over CircleCI with the same xcodebuild command so I can't just set it manually. Does anyone know how to get the terminal commands to work with locations?

Edit: Also tried the following, both with set-simulator-location and xcrun simctl location 'iPhone 14' set <lat, long> both with and without shutting down the simulator and xcodebuild still doesn't have a location. If I open the simulator afterwards though, the location is set. It seems to be only for the duration of the xcodebuild run that any attempt at setting a location is completely ignored.

```
xcrun simctl boot 'iPhone 14'
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/
set-simulator-location -c lat long
xcrun simtcl shutdown 'iPhone 14'
xcodebuild ...
```

Edit 2: Figured it out just going with an AppleScript to set the location. CircleCI doesn't seem to like me keeping the simulator open and runs way faster with it being closed after the location is set, but in that case the location is, surprise, ignored. So this seems to be the only way that works. Here's what I run:

```
xcrun simctl boot 'iPhone 14'
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/
chmod 755 location_script.scpt
osascript location_script.scpt
xcodebuild ...
```

location_script.scpt:

```
tell application "Simulator"
activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "Simulator"
click menu item "Custom Location..." of menu of menu item "Location" of menu "Features" of menu bar 1
set value of text field 1 of window 1 to <latitude>
set value of text field 2 of window 1 to <longitude>
click button "OK" of window 1
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi. I was investigating this problem too. I'm using xcode14.2 and running "xcrun simctl location \(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UDID"] ?? "") set \(lat),\(long)" via SBTUITestTunnel, right before calling self.app.launch() in my XCUI test. It works fine. I launch test via "xcodebuild test" command too. The only difference is you passing device name instead of UDID. However, mocking location via simctl does not work if I launch test from Xcode. So I had too keep regular applesimutils call, which is believe hidden under "set-simulator-location" command in your case.